# What order should I read the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen?

Tags: suggested-order, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

I want to read the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen, but looking around it's managed to confuse me with the proliferation of volumes, chapters and timelines.  What order should I read the various editions in, and how do they fit into an overall timeline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt, read the by publishing order. Which is, to date:

1. League of Extraordinary Gentlemen Volume 1 (Set in Victorian times)
2. League of Extraordinary Gentlemen Volume 2 (Closely follows the previous volume)
3. The Black Dossier (The year 1958)
4. League of Extraordinary Gentlemen Volume 3: Century (Starts in 1910, passes by the 1970's, and ends in 2009)

The Black Dossier is more of a standalone story though.

Comment: Ok, so http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/league-extraordinary-gentlemen/id460789459?mt=11 and http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-league-extraordinary-gentlemen/id461172175?mt=11 are actually parts 1 and 2 of Vol 3?

Comment: @dlanod - Yes. Issues 1 & 2 of "LXG Volume 3: Century"

Comment: Century 2009 is the third of volume 3

Answer (score 4):

As of 2015, there has also been a spin off story, [Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen_(comics)#Nemo_Trilogy).

So a reading order with this spin off trilogy included, could be:

- Volume I
- Volume II
- Black Dossier
- Volume III
- Nemo Trilogy

The Nemo trilogy are set in:

- Heart of Ice  1925 AD
- The Roses of Berlin   1941 AD
- River of Ghosts   1975 AD

Answer (score 1):

To read chronologically:

- Vol 1-2
- Century: 1910
- Heart of Ice (1925)
- The Roses of Berlin (1941)
- Black Dossier (1958)
- Century: 1969
- River of Ghosts (1975)
- Century: 2009

Comment: Any reason that chronologically is the best method and none of the other suggestions?